# User Control with custom ItemsSource dependency property

Tags: wpf, user-controls, mvvm

I've got a UserControl with an ItemsSource property. As the base UserControl class does not implement ItemsSource, I had to create my own dependency property like this:

```
#region ItemsSource Dependency Property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MonthViewControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnItemsSourceChanged));

    static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (obj as MonthViewControl).OnItemsSourceChanged(e);
    }

    private void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshLayout();
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (base.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty) as IEnumerable);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Now in my ViewModel I have an Events property which is an ICollectionView of EventItem items like so:

```
private ObservableCollection<Controls.EventCalendar.EventItem> eventItems;
    private CollectionViewSource events;
    public System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView Events
    {
        get
        {
            if (events == null)
            {
                events = new CollectionViewSource();
                events.Source = eventItems;
            }

            return events.View;
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm facing is that in my View, when I bind to the Events property, and I add an Item to eventItems, the UserControl won't fire the ItemsSourceChanged event and hence not update the UI. 
For the sake of testing I added a simple listbox to the view which also binds to the Events property. That works like a charm. Updates to eventItems observableCollection are reflected in the ListBox.

I'm figuring it has something to do with my ItemsSource dependency property. Maybe I would need to use a Custom Control which inherits form ItemsControl instead of a UserControl?

To help you understand my problem: I'm trying to create a calendar like control which shows events/agenda entries (similar to Google Calendar). It works like a charm. The UI is updated when the control is resized. The only thing that's left is the automagical update once the ItemsSource changes.

Hope someone can help.

EDIT: The moment I posted I realized that the event can't be fired as the ItemsSource property does not change. It is the underlying collection that changes. However, I'm not how to handle that. What do I need to implement to make this work. Just a hint would be enough. I don't need every implementation details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opening the PresentationFramework.dll within Reflector and looking at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl showed the following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), 
   typeof(ItemsControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, 
   new PropertyChangedCallback(ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged)));

private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ItemsControl control = (ItemsControl) d;
    IEnumerable oldValue = (IEnumerable) e.OldValue;
    IEnumerable newValue = (IEnumerable) e.NewValue;
    ItemValueStorageField.ClearValue(d);
    if ((e.NewValue == null) && !BindingOperations.IsDataBound(d, ItemsSourceProperty))
    {
        control.Items.ClearItemsSource();
    }
    else
    {
        control.Items.SetItemsSource(newValue);
    }
    control.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
}
```

Not knowing what `RefreshLayout` does my hunch is that it has something to do with the way the `ObservableCollection<T>` is being wrapped as the above code is oblivious to what the concrete collection type is and it would therefore be handled by the type being wrapped; in this case an `ObservableCollection<T>` Try modifying your property as seen below to return the default view and adjust your `ItemsSource` property to be more akin to the above code from the framework and work backwards from there.

```
private ObservableCollection<Controls.EventCalendar.EventItem> eventItems;
private ICollectionview eventsView;
public System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView Events
{
    get
    {
        if (eventsView == null)
            eventsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(eventItems);
        return eventsView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I'm going to mark your answer as 'Answer' as it looks like the way to go. However, I can't tell for sure as I haven't tried it. Indeed, I decided to redesign the control from a UserControl to a CustomControl which inherits from ItemsControl and that seems (for now) to solve the problem.