# Replace NULL with a default Value in an ItemsSource IEnumerable

Tags: c#, wpf, list, custom-controls, ienumerable

I'm having a **`Custom Control`** derived from an **`ItemsControl`**.

I got the idea from [Two-Way Binding Issue of Unknown Object in WPF Custom Control Dependency Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187879/two-way-binding-issue-of-unknown-object-in-wpf-custom-control-dependency-propert)

In the above Question, they use the Collection in the View Model

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
{
    get { return _collection; }
    set
    {
        _collection = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Collection"));
    }
}
```

The XAML Code is

```
<Window x:Class="SampleControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleControl" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:BTextBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
            ProviderCommand="{Binding AutoBTextCommand}" 
            AutoItemsSource="{Binding SuggCollection}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If I removed the `new ObservableCollection<string>();` then it will became

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _collection;

public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
{
    get { return _collection; }
    set
    {
        _collection = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Collection"));
    }
}
```

Now the Property **`Collection`** hold the value **`NULL`**. This Property is bind in the `ItemsSource`. So, how could I push the data into the ItemsSource

The CustomControl Method is

```
private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var tb = d as BTextBox;
    if ((e.NewValue != null) && ((tb.ItemsSource as IList) != null)) {
        foreach (var item in e.NewValue as IEnumerable) {
            (tb.ItemsSource as IList).Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

In this method, it checks for **`NULL`**, IF the `ItemsSource` is **`NOT NULL`**, then it pushes the data.

`if ((e.NewValue != null) && ((tb.ItemsSource as IList) != null))`. If the **`ItemsSource`** is **`NOT NULL`**, then only then item gets pushed into the collection `(tb.ItemsSource as IList).Add(item);`

Kindly assist me, how to assign the Value in a **`Null-able IEnumerable`** ?

Comment: `IF the ItemsSource is NOT NULL, then it pushes the data` is kinda vague...

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Kindly see the above method, it checks for `NULL` ~ `if ((e.NewValue != null) && ((tb.ItemsSource as IList) != null))`. If the ItemsSource is not NULL, then only then item gets pushed into the collection `(tb.ItemsSource as IList).Add(item);`.

Comment: But, you're binding the `Collection` to the ItemsSource in Xaml, but you're adding those items also to the `AutoItemsSource`?

Comment: When I bind an item in xaml, I create the collection only ones.._(in constructor)_

Comment: Why not use this: `tb.ItemsSource = e.NewValue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Can add the Item, before adding the Item we need to create an Instance

```
if(this.ItemsSource == null)
{
    this.ItemsSource = (new List<object>()).AsEnumerable();
}

(tb.ItemsSource as IList).Add(item);
```

Now, it won't throw any **`NULL` Reference exception**.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add data to the ObservableCollection, just add a constructor before that. It is my usual practice.

For example,

```
Collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
...add data to the collection here
```

Depending on your situation.

**Edit**

If you want a solution on the Custom Control level, maybe try something like this:

```
var tb = d as BTextBox;
if (((tb.ItemsSource as IList) == null))
    tb.ItemsSource = new IList<string>(); // or new ObservableCollection, List, or any suitable datatype, just to give default values
if ((e.NewValue != null) && ((tb.ItemsSource as IList) != null)) { // probably remove the checking for ((tb.ItemsSource as IList) != null) since we initialized it
...
```

Comment: Here I need the generic solution not in the ViewModel level, need solution in Custom Control Level.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [User Control with custom ItemsSource dependency property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4539697/6741868). It is interesting how they used e.oldValue and e.newValue to check and handle null case.